# How to filter two table in powerbi according one or more conditions

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables, one contains all the file IDs and decision code (this table contains unique entries) and the other contains the rules that were applied to it (this one contains duplicate entries on rules and file IDs).

The two tables are linked by the file ID on which a one-to-many relationship has been established.
The second table contains duplicate entries on rules and file ID, i.e. different rules or a single rule can be applied to an ID.

I posted an example of my two tables to give you an idea. See picture [Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei3FV.png)

What I want to do now is to get this snapshot:
[Final results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQLPH.png)
I would like to count every file ID that has had one of the listed rules applied to it and has a decision code of A or R.

Please note that the rules are not static, they may change as they are updated.

I tried all the possibilities that I know of DAX but I had no solutions.

Thank you in advance for your precious help.

Comment: Consider adding table data to the question so that we can copy/paste into our own PowerBI. I learned for stackoverflow Questions, to model the data in Excel, paste it into a web page that converts your pasted Excel into markdown; Then cram the markdown into your Qs.
And in your Final Result pgn, consider adding the totals to the cross tabd table.  :)

Comment: Please refer to the pic @MikeG

Comment: Is it the case that you'd like whomever is willing to help you to first do some data-entry busy work on your behalf?  (Work which you could otherwise do for everyhelper by including as part of your question.)  
I only ask because I'm regularly helped so long as I include data in the question. I found that by not including the data, the helpfuls may doubt ones sincerity.